# How do I compare dates in rails without the year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, compare

I'm trying to find all users with birthdays in the coming 2 weeks.

I tried the following:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["DOB > ? and DOB <= ?", Date.today, 2.weeks.from_now])
```

which obviously doesn't work because the 'year' in the DOB doesn't equal to this year.

I need to only compare the months and the days.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Salil's answer, I have derived the following to make it work for sqlite:

```
arr = []
(0..14).each { |i| arr << (Date.today + i.day).yday }
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["cast(strftime('%j', DOB) AS int) in (?)", arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform mysql method on your dob column

Something like following

```
  SELECT FROM users  
         WHERE DAYOFYEAR(dob)in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
```

You can use functions like WEEK whichever works for you Ref [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for mysql function

In ruby

```
arr=[]
(0..13).each{|i| arr << (Date.today+i.day).day }
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["DAYOFYEAR(DOB) in (?)", arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach for postgresql:

```
scope :with_bday, -> (from, to) {
    where("EXTRACT(DOY FROM birthday)::int BETWEEN ? AND ?", *[
        from.yday,
        to.yday
    ])
}
```

Comment: This gives problems when it's a leap year

Answer (score 0):

This may help in changing the date format for comparison as by default it will take Date.today.year.

```
              Date.strptime("{ #{DOB.month}, #{DOB.date} }", "{ %m, %d }").
```

Date.strptime("{ 9, 10 }", "{ %m, %d }")     gives

```
<Date: 2011-09-10 (4911629/2,0,2299161)>
```

Do post if you get some code for direct comparison.

Comment: Is there an SQL way to do the same thing? Because I can't just stick ruby code into my conditions